# Plot multiple functions on one figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm struggling to plot multiple functions on one figure.

Here is the code that I have:

```
syms t a;
a=0.9514;
F1=0.5*sqrt(3*t^2);
F2=-0.28375*t^2+1.155*a*(t-a)+1;
F3=1;
E1=diff(F1,t);
E2=diff(F2,t);
E3=diff(F3,t);
```

I want to plot E1, E2 and E3, each only within a certain range, to make a "composite" line.

I've tried plotting with `ezplot` but that only plots the last one.
`plot` and `fplot` give errors.

```
ezplot((3^(1/2)*t)/(2*(t^2)^(1/2)),[0,0.5*a])
hold on
ezplot((231*a)/200 - (231*t)/400,[0.5*a,2*a])
hold on
ezplot(0,[2*a,2.5*a])
```

(E3=0)

How can I get the functions to plot all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the x limit.

```
xlim([0 2.5*a])
```

Answer (score 2):

2 things:

1.-  The last line of your code throws an error. Its wrong.

2.-  The plots are there, its just you dont' see them. Try adding `axis([0 1 0 1])` to zoom out! Try to figure out which are your limits (not 0-1, 0-1 for sure ;))

Comment: Thanks! I see why it gives an error. Initially I had the function names in the ezplot, like ezplot(E1,......), but at some stage I replaced that with what their actual values were, so when putting 0, without thinking, I caused that error. 

    But setting the axes worked! Thanks!

Comment: @Mierzen no problem! Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a range of numbers for `t` instead of symbols,

```
a=0.9514;
t1 = linspace(0.,0.5*a,1000);
t2 = linspace(0.5*a,2*a,1000);
t3 = linspace(2*a,2.5*a,1000);

F1=0.5*sqrt(3*t1.^2);
F2=-0.28375*t2.^2+1.155*a*(t2-a)+1;
F3=ones(size(t3));
E1=diff(F1)./diff(t1);
E2=diff(F2)./diff(t2);
E3=diff(F3)./diff(t3);
plot(t1(1:end-1), E1)
hold all
plot(t2(1:end-1), E2)
plot(t3(1:end-1), E3)
```

Which gives the following,

[image]